# How to accomplish a optional childview?

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views, sproutcore-controllers

I have a view with two child views, and want the second view optionally to disappear, that is disabled including the dataBinding, and resize the first view, and vice versa. I need some hints or (pseudo) code how to accomplish this. Thx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few views in SproutCore which do this in some way or another. While it is not the best example, have a look at [the experimental select search view](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/blob/master/frameworks/experimental/frameworks/select_ext/views/select_search_view.js#L68).

You are going to need to override createChildViews to set up the bindings manually, so you can also take them down when required.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting the picture. My childViews contains a lot of data and are vertically stacked, and both have a much time consuming query, I want depending on the user's choice, disable/remove the  second view. I have looked at autoresize, flowedlayout, invisibleBinding, isEnabled etc etc,  and when the second view is not enabled, it is not visible anymore but the gained "space" is not filled, in other words the first view is not resized.

Comment: There is another way to do it, which is to build to view classes, where one has the second view, and the other doesn't. You can then decide on which view class to use, based on the users preference, for example stored using the user defaults: http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.UserDefaults&src=false
This approach assumes that you won't switch. If you indeed don't switch, you won't have the problem of doubling the bindings as the bindings only get activated when the view instance is created.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I was thinking of applying the .adjust layout option, but building two views (one with and one without the second view), is also an option. Anyway the user already have an preference pane, and this will be an extra option. Regarding the code request, I will try and learn first by myself, anyway thanks alot.